# show select all in Autocomplete

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I would like my input box to display 'ALL' instead of showing other things when I click on 'select all'.

I tried to add a condition in the getOptionLabel function, but besides displaying 'ALL', it still shows other items.

```jsx
<Autocomplete
  multiple
  label="學生*"
  id="createStudent"
  options={
    studentOptions(index).length > 0
    ? [
      {
        value: SELECT_ALL, name: 'ALL',
      },
      ...studentOptions(index)
    ] : []
  }
  disableCloseOnSelect
  variant='outlined'
  getOptionLabel={(option) => {
    return (
      option.value === SELECT_ALL
    ? 'ALL'
    : option.name
    );
  }
    
  }
  renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
    <li {...props}>
      <Checkbox
        icon={icon}
        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        checked={selected}
      />
      {option.name}
    </li>
  )}
  limitTags={1}
  renderInput={(params) => {
    return (
      <TextField 
      {...params} 
      label="學生*"
     />
    );
  }}
  value={formData.createClass[index].studentList}
  key={studentOptions(index)}
  onChange={handleStudentChange(index, studentOptions(index))}
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>option.name === value.value || ''}
/>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the display of selected options, you can use the [renderTags](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) property.

In your case, I think I would write something like this:

```
<Autocomplete
  //all your previous properties
  renderTags={(selectedOptions) => {
    const isAllSelected = selectedOptions.findIndex((o) => o.value === "SELECT_ALL") !== -1
    if (isAllSelected ) return <Chip label={"All"} />;
    else return selectedOptions.map((o.name) => <Chip label={o} />);
  }}
/>
```

You can use this example as a reference:

[image: Edit material UI Autocomplete sticky Select All action (Custom tags)]